# crash on "new" when calling a c++ dll from vb

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, crash

I'm creating a dll from a cpp project.
When calling this dll from a vb project, the app crashes.
with this error message:

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in...
    Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often 
    an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I can debug the dll, and see that the crash is in this line

```
    carEngine = new CAREngine ();
```

**The CAREngine constructor is empty. What could cause this crash?**

Here's the code:

C++ .h file:

```
    #include "CarEngine.h"

    class Engine
    {
    public:
        bool __declspec(dllexport) initEngine(LPCTSTR DBfileName);
    private:
        CAREngine* carEngine;
    };
```

C++ .cpp file:

```
    bool Engine::initEngine(LPCTSTR DBfileName)
    {
        logText("Engine Loading start");
        carEngine = new CAREngine ();  //<- Crash is here
        ...
    }
```

VB:

```
    <DllImport("myengine.dll", EntryPoint:="?    
    initEngine@Engine@@QAE_NPBD@Z")> _
    Public Function initEngine(ByVal lpString As String) As Boolean
    End Function

    ...

    initEngine("C:\1.txt")
```

Comment: as I wrote - the CAREngine constructor is empty

Comment: Can you show more of the VB code? Like how you create the `Engine` instance? Or do you just call the `initEngine` member function without any `Engine` instance?

Comment: this is all the vb code. there is no Engine Class in VB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initEngine` is an instance method, but you're treating it as a standalone method.

When you call an instance method theres is an implicit parameter that holds the value of `this`, and is the address of the variable on the left side of the `.` or `->`. However, you have not create an instance of `Engine`, you've just called a member function. The string you're passing in will be used as the value of the `this` and the `lpString` parameter will end up being some random value that's on the stack.

The code will crash on assignment to `carEngine` because the compiler actually treats it as `this->carEngine`, and as `this` points to something that isn't a `Engine` it will fail.

As an aside, exporting C++ member functions for use in C# is hard work, as you've found out! You have to link by the mangled name, and the mangling can change from compiler version to compiler version.

If you really need to use C++ when you might want to consider using managed C++. Alternativly it's common to expose C functions that wrap the member functions and take an opaque value which is actually a pointer to the instance they operate on. For example

```
void *EngineCreate();
void EngineInitialize(void *engine)
void EngineSetName(void *engine, const TCHAR *name)
// etc
// etc
```

Comment: I don't want to hijack the question, but (my c++ skills aren't the best) why will the passed string be used as the value of `this`? I understand that there's no instance for `initEngine` to use, but why would try to use the first parameter to the function??

Comment: All non-static member functions need to have a value for `this`. Under the hood this is typically passed in as the first parameter. So `initEngine` is treated by the compiler as `initEngine(Engine *this, LPCTSTR DBFilename)`. You've told the VB compiler that the first parameter is a string, but from the point of view of the C++ compiler the first parameter is a pointer to the `Engine` instance to operate on.

Comment: I understand. So the first parameter will always be treated as `(yourType *this...)` in the absence of `this->...`. Nice answer.

Comment: The first parameter is always `this`, regardless of whether you put `this->` or not. Likewise, any access to member variables will always be treated as `this->variable`, even if you didn't mention `this`.